# Should I see a difference with the upgraded SCOPE?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I always bring 2 snipers in my squad, that are equipped with a SCOPE.

I upgraded the SCOPE in the foundry, and the description of the upgrade said something along the lines of "highlights sensitive areas in the target"

However, I didn't notice anything different in the following field mission, is the effect noticeable or is it just increased accuracy with no visual difference?

I don't need to build new SCOPEs, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "highlights sensitive points" is just flavor text.  The effect of the SCOPE upgrade is a 10% increase in the likelihood of critical hits.  There is no change to weapon accuracy.

This boost applies to ones you already own, as well as new ones you build.

The [XCOM Wikia](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/S.C.O.P.E._Upgrade) says that this is bugged, but it appears to just be a bug in the display logic.  According to their article, you won't see the 10% bonus unless you pull up the "additional info" screen.